# Arrange elements regardless of their size

Tags: css

I create a list of categories A-Z. To this end, I use ul and li elements. I want the elements to be arranged one after the other regardless of the height of the elements. My current code places the elements correctly, but if there are many elements in the block, the error appears and the puzzle breaks

My actual code:

```css
ul > li{
  display:inline-block;
  padding:10px;
  background:#eee;
  width:calc(100% / 4);
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

ul > li > ul{
  display:block;
}

ul > li > ul > li{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
      <h2>A</h2>
      <ul>
          <li>Text 1</li>
          <li>Text 2</li>
          <li>Text 3</li>
          <li>Text 4</li>
          <li>Text 5</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h2>B</h2>
      <ul>
          <li>Text 1</li>
          <li>Text 2</li>
          <li>Text 3</li>
          <li>Text 4</li>
          <li>Text 5</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h2>C</h2>
      <ul>
          <li>Text 1</li>
          <li>Text 2</li>
          <li>Text 3</li>
          <li>Text 4</li>
          <li>Text 5</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h2>D</h2>
      <ul>
          <li>Text 1</li>
          <li>Text 2</li>
          <li>Text 3</li>
          <li>Text 4</li>
          <li>Text 5</li>
          <li>Text 6</li>
          <li>Text 7</li>
          <li>Text 8</li>
          <li>Text 9</li>
          <li>Text 10</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h2>E</h2>
      <ul>
          <li>Text 1</li>
          <li>Text 2</li>
          <li>Text 3</li>
          <li>Text 4</li>
          <li>Text 5</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

How could I fix it?

Comment: Have you considered using a table? This looks like tabular data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just top align the immediate `li` content after `ul` with `vertical-align: top`;

```css
ul > li{
  display:inline-block;
  padding:10px;
  background:#eee;
  width:calc(100% / 4);
  box-sizing:border-box;
  vertical-align: top;
}

ul > li > ul{
  display:block;
}

ul > li > ul > li{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
      <h2>A</h2>
      <ul>
          <li>Text 1</li>
          <li>Text 2</li>
          <li>Text 3</li>
          <li>Text 4</li>
          <li>Text 5</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h2>B</h2>
      <ul>
          <li>Text 1</li>
          <li>Text 2</li>
          <li>Text 3</li>
          <li>Text 4</li>
          <li>Text 5</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h2>C</h2>
      <ul>
          <li>Text 1</li>
          <li>Text 2</li>
          <li>Text 3</li>
          <li>Text 4</li>
          <li>Text 5</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h2>D</h2>
      <ul>
          <li>Text 1</li>
          <li>Text 2</li>
          <li>Text 3</li>
          <li>Text 4</li>
          <li>Text 5</li>
          <li>Text 6</li>
          <li>Text 7</li>
          <li>Text 8</li>
          <li>Text 9</li>
          <li>Text 10</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h2>E</h2>
      <ul>
          <li>Text 1</li>
          <li>Text 2</li>
          <li>Text 3</li>
          <li>Text 4</li>
          <li>Text 5</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```